# Build Emacs: cannot find -lpng15

Tags: compiling, emacs

I'm trying to build Emacs 24.4 and this error occured:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng15
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [temacs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nick/apps/emacs-24.4/src'
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong, and the possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong is that you don't have `libpng15` installed. You can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/1.5.20 and install. Then try to compile Emacs again.

Comment: Thank you. I tried several methods, and moved from Gnome-shell to KDE, and finally to i3wm. At last, emacs was successfully compiled.

Comment: @Nick: why wouldn't you just use a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)?